# Looking for a method to get button ID when pushed

Tags: c#, events, button

Building a program in which when a button is pushed, it saves that pushed event as a "1" in an array. I want to have 3 buttons, so the array would have 3 fields full of 0s or 1s (Pushed or not pushed) during a dictated length of time. Not too familiar with C#, so I have no idea where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: start with delegates and events and you will get the idea. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you should get familiar with the C# language. A good way to start:  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/

I don't know what your final aim is, but if you really want to go with arrays then try something like this:

```
// declare it as class member
int[] buttonStates = new int[3] {0, 0, 0}; // immediate initialization
```

There are several ways to handle button presses. It's depending on the platform you're developing on: WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF, etc.?

But in general:
 your button event handlers should contain the code that places the 1s in the array.

```
// in the first button handler:
buttonStates[0] = 1;

// in the second button handler:
buttonStates[1] = 1;

// in the third button handler:
buttonStates[2] = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the provided answers and as your title suggests to get Button ID. To identify each button uniquely, you can use 'Name'(unique name for the element to be identified) or 'Tag' (can be used to store custom information about the element) properties of a button. 
You can set the button ID in the tag property of button:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = 1;
```

Then in your event handler

```
private void Btn_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
Button b = (Button)sender;
int btnTag = (int)b.Tag;   //check the Id
}
```

and can refer to the button using this 'ID'